# How to convert this AS2 code to AS3 ? (Gallery images)

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I'm a flash newbie. I followed this tutorial. Here's the url
virtualhacker.wikispaces.com/file/view/funci%C3%B3n+para+el+bot%C3%B3n+Siguiente.pdf/156572951/funci%C3%B3n%20para%20el%20bot%C3%B3n%20Siguiente.pdf

Is an images gallery.

I implemented the code in AS2 and it runs pretty good.
This code was missing in the tutorial

```
 The code to center the images

sput_mc._x=(500-233)/2;
sput_mc._y=(250-50)/2;
```

and the if conditional statement code to go to the picture number 1,

```
if (npictures==5){ npictures=1
            }
```

without the code above it give you this error

```
Error opening URL 'file:/gal/Gallery/undefined'
```

Here's the complete AS2 code:

```
var npictures:Number=1
var images:Array=new Array()
images[1]="images/image_01.jpg"
images[2]="images/image_02.jpg"
images[3]="images/image_03.jpg"
images[4]="images/image_04.jpg"

// TO CENTER THE IMAGE
sput_mc._x=(500-233)/2;
sput_mc._y=(250-50)/2;

number_txt.text=npictures
sput_mc.loadMovie(images[npictures])

neut_btn.onPress=function(){
    npictures=Number(number_txt.text)
    sput_mc.loadMovie(images[npictures])
}

prev_btn.onPress=function(){
    npictures--
    number_txt.text=npictures
    sput_mc.loadMovie(images[npictures])
}

//remember the If statement to avoid the error
forw_btn.onPress=function(){
    npictures++
    if (npictures==5){ npictures=1
        }
    number_txt.text=npictures
    sput_mc.loadMovie(images[npictures])
}
```

Can an experience flash AS3 code master figure out the code in AS3. Please help!

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Thank you guys

I did it after reading this **as3 references**

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?p=989392
http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/imgload/

**Is this a good way to do it or there is no need the toString thing or null, addChild?**

```
var npictures:Number=1

//the addChild null
var sput_mc:sput_mc=new sput_mc();
this.addChild(sput_mc);

var images:Array = new Array(
'pic1.jpg', 
'pic2.jpg',
'pic3.jpg',
'pic4.jpg');


sput_mc.x=130;
sput_mc.y=90;

//toString
number_txt.text=npictures.toString();
sput_mc.load(new URLRequest(images[npictures]));



neut_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onEntClick);

function onEntClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    number_txt.text=npictures.toString();
    sput_mc.load(new URLRequest(images[npictures]));

}


forw_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onForwClick);

function onForwClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
{

    npictures++
    if (npictures==4){ npictures=0
        }       

}


prev_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onBacklick);
function onBackClick(e:MouseEvent):void 

{       
        //
    npictures--
    if (npictures==4){ npictures=0
        }
    // toString()   
    number_txt.text=npictures.toString();
    sput_mc.load(new URLRequest(images[npictures]));

}
```

Comment: Have you given it a try yet? If so, where did you get stuck? If not, give it a go and come back when you run into a problem.

Comment: This is not a "translation for free" site. Please try it yourself. If you get stuck somewhere, come back and we will try to help you.

Comment: Don't ask for code translations; learn as3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ask these type of questions... they won't help other users.  But learn as3 - seriously, don't get other people to do your work for you.  But here, take it-

```
var npictures:Number=1
var images:Array=new Array()
images[1]="images/image_01.jpg"
images[2]="images/image_02.jpg"
images[3]="images/image_03.jpg"
images[4]="images/image_04.jpg"

// TO CENTER THE IMAGE
sput_mc.x=(500-233)/2;
sput_mc.y=(250-50)/2;

number_txt.text=npictures
sput_mc.load(new URLRequest(images[npictures]));

neut_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, soup);

function soup(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    npictures=Number(number_txt.text)
    sput_mc.load(new URLRequest(images[npictures]));
}

prev_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, watevadude);

function watevadude(e:MouseEvent):void
    npictures--
    number_txt.text=npictures
    sput_mc.load(new URLRequest(images[npictures]));
}

//remember the If statement to avoid the error
forw_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hey);

function hey(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    npictures++;
    if (npictures==5){ npictures=1;
        }
    number_txt.text=npictures;
    sput_mc.load(new URLRequest(images[npictures]));
}
```

Don't ask these questions... I'm the only guy who's stupid enough to do this, so don't expect anyone else to do it.  Why don't you PAY someone to do it or something?  OR LEARN AS3!!!

Comment: Thank you guys, could you check the code I did it slightly different.

Comment: @gunt your code was fine.  If the variable was a number or integer, you need to use toString(), otherwise you don't

Answer (score 1):

The main differences you'll meet will be:

_x and _y became x and y.

`loadMovie` does not exist anymore. You must use a [`Loader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) instead of a `Sprite`.

The event listeners do not work that way in AS3, for instance, the click listener:

```
forw_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onForwardClick);

private function onForwardClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  //action
}
```

For the rest, I must agree with the commenters, you have to give it a try yourself and THEN ask for help on specific points.